# avoiding scaling on a webpage

Tags: html, css

Hello I am building a webpage that consists of tables, its been successfully built, but the only problem is that when my page is uploaded, the way it looks varies on different screens, so i am trying to have a fixed size using css, so that my page looks unique on all screens, this is what I have tried

`style="height: 100%;"`, for my tables and body tag

But it makes my page not to scroll, but the content and images are looking terribly stretched. can anyone suggest what I can do to have a well looking webpage that would come out uniquely on all webpages

Comment: Learn CSS more..

Comment: can u pls profer a solution 4 dis

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design. Learn responsive design. Get better at CSS as @Mr.Alien suggested. Learn to fish instead of asking for fish!

Comment: First solution, don't use `table` for designing layouts, second solution, learn CSS indepth, 3rd solution, you might want to take a look at `@media` queries

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `Media Queries` - http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: It would help if you posted your `HTML` and `CSS`. Rather than expecting a generic answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read on how to use the `<div>` tag in combination with CSS. Much easier to design your homepage using the `<div>` tag rather than `<table>`. Also it will help you when you need to make layout changes for your homepage in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Give elements a fixed width rather than percentage to avoid stretching.

More ideally, look into learning media queries.